# onFormSubmit | error when triggering response

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Trying to set up a onFormSubmit response trigger (for a Google form) but getting error "Cannot read property 'response' of undefined". Also getting a failed or timed out message when viewing trigger executions. Searched on so many forums for an answer to this and no luck. Is it an issue with the code or how I've set up my trigger?

Help with this is much appreciated.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

 // Open the sheet which stores the responses
 var ssID = 'Sheet ID' // Replace with spreadsheet ID
 var ssName = 'Form responses' // Replace with sheet name
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName(ssName);

 // #1 - Identify the requestor's email address and save it to the sheet.
 var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
 sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 7).setValue(email);

 // #2 - Get the response ID and save it to the sheet.
 var responseID = e.response.getId();
 sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 8).setValue(response_id); 

 // #3 - Set the status of the request to 'Pending'.
 sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 9).setValue('Pending');

 // Create variables for email
 var items = e.source.getItems();
 var manager_email = e.response.getResponseForItem(items[3]).getResponse()
 var subject = "A time-off request has been submitted";

 // Include form data in the body of the email
 var message = "";
 for(var i in items)
 message += "\n\n" + items[i].getTitle() + ":" + 
 e.response.getResponseForItem(items[i]).getResponse();

 // #4 - Insert approve and deny links within the body of the email
 message += "\n\nClick below link to approve: \n"
 https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxdS3cUP_oSjfphDaSNkn_5GuxxlPG6czVHH_wGJ2OxImqFASmZ/exec?id=" + responseID + "&status=Approved \n\n" + "Click below link to deny: \n 
 //script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxdS3cUP_oSjfphDaSNkn_5GuxxlPG6czVHH_wGJ2OxImqFASmZ/exec?id=" + responseID + "&status=Denied";

 // #5 - Email the manager the request information
 MailApp.sendEmail(manager_email, subject, message);

}
```

Comment: Welcome. Would you please supply the entire error message - it has much more information in it, specifically which line of code that triggered the error. It looks as though your script is bound to a spreadsheet, is that right? `response` is an [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) available when bound to the Form, and this would explain the error.

Comment: _Also getting a failed or timed out message when viewing trigger executions._ Just noticed this. I think it will probably be resolved once the script is debugged.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your reply. The error is occurring on line 13. I now have it working. ```var responseID = e.response.getId();``` Apart from a typo, the error only shows when running the function from script editor. It appears to trigger OK when submitting a form.

Comment: When you execute from the editor you don' t have this object as a input parameter. So it's normal that your input variable `e` is not defined when executing from the editor.